# IPv6 socket works in Mono console app but not Unity app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, ipv6, socketexception

I have a problem with some code that uses sockets. I want to connect my script over IPv6 but I receive a SocketException when I run this script in Unity. This code works perfectly as a Console Application Project in MonoDevelop:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace socketIPv6
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Socket s;
            s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("ff15::2");
            s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new IPv6MulticastOption(ip));
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 26000);
            s.Bind(ipep);

            while (true) {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                s.Receive (b);
                string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (b, 0, b.Length);
                Console.WriteLine (str.Trim ());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the same code (I only changed `"Console.WriteLine()"` for `"Debug.Log()"`) doesn't work as a Unity Project. This code breaks with the exception: `"SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used."` Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the version of the Mono framework you're linking against from a console app may be different than Unity's mono framework.

This may partially answer what's going on:

Decompiling `Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.dll` with ILSpy shows at various places a dependency on

```
internal static void Socket.CheckProtocolSupport()
```

which, among one other related check therein, attempts to read from the .NET config file(s) from section `system.net/settings`. If you look at `Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\etc\mono\2.0\machine.config` it has `system.net/settings/<ipv6 enabled="false"/>`.

So either that config file is irrelevant or stale, or it appears Unity specifically has turned off or does not support IPv6 sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ".Net 2.0 Subset" api compatibility in the player settings. I was running in this same thing and it was because we were using the full ".Net 2.0"

This is the bug report if you're interested: https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?804510_c5ei44diq6ktnh1u